# Number of path components of a function space

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X,Y$ be compact topological spaces. $Map(X,Y)$ is the set of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ with the compact-open topology (but any reasonable topology should do, am I wrong?).

What strategies could one follow in order to compute the number of path components of $Map(X,Y)$? I believe this number should also be the number of $[X,Y]$ homotopy classes of maps $X\rightarrow Y$, is it not? (If there is disparity between the two, I am interested in the second).

I am reading some literature about the topology of $Map(X,Y)$ and there are some interesting results about the topology of the connected components, but what about the number of the connected components themselves?

For example, intuitively, I can say

$[X_1\vee X_2, Y]\approx [X_1,Y]\times[X_2,Y]$

Is there a result for the a generic union? E.g., how far is the following from the truth when $X=X_1\cup X_2$?

$[X,Y]\approx[X_1/(X_1\cap X_2),Y]\times [X_2/(X_1\cap X_2),Y]\times [X_1\cap X_2,Y]$

Finally, what if I am interested in smooth maps instead of continuous? If the manifolds I am working with are 'well behaved', can I forget about the difference?

Comment: A path in $Y^X$ (another way of writing $Map(X,Y)$) is a map $I\to Y^X$, i.e. an element in $(Y^X)^I$. A homotopy from $X$ to $Y$ is a map $X\times I\to Y$, i.e. an element of $Y^{X\times I}$. If $X$ is locally compact, then there is a natural bijection between the sets $(Y^X)^I$ and $Y^{X\times I}$ sending a path $p$ to the map $\bar p:(x,t)\mapsto p(t)(x)$. This way, a path between two maps $f$ and $g$ is basically the same as a homotopy from $f$ to $g$, so the path components of $Y^X$ are the homotopy classes of map $X\to Y$, provided $X$ is locally compact.

Comment: Every continuous map is homotopic to a smooth one, and every continuous map from a manifold with boundary that's smooth on the boundary is homotopic (without changing the map on the boundary) to a smooth map. By considering $M$ without boundary and $M \times I$ one recovers that smooth homotopy classes of maps are in bijection with continuous homotopy classes of maps. (Actually we have better: the inclusion $\text{Smooth}(M,N) \to \text{Cont}(M,N)$ is a homotopy equivalence. Proof: same idea.)

Comment: @StefanHamcke, do you know counterexample if $X$ is not locally compact?