# Is a path homotopy equivalence class a path component?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\Omega=\Omega (X;a,b)$ be a path space of $X$ from $a\in X$ to $b\in X$ with a compact-open topology. 
For any $f\in \Omega$, we can consider a homotopy equivalence class $[f]$.

I want to prove or disprove that these classes are path components of $\Omega$.

I first tried to prove it is path connected based on the following sketch, but I'm not sure it is well proved.

Also I 'm stuck on proving $[f]\cup [g]$ is not path connected if $g\notin [f]$.

(**EDITED:** I added my proof for the converse, but I'm not sure it is valid)

Any help will be appreciated.

---

$\forall g,h \in [f]$, there exists a continuous function $H:I^2\rightarrow X$ such that $H(t,0)=g(t), H(t,1)=h(t) \ \forall t \in I$

Then we can define $J:I\rightarrow \Omega \ $ by $J(s)(t)=H(t,s)$ and it suffices to show that $J$ is continuous.

For an open subset $U$ of $X$ and a compact subset $K$ of $I$, let $L_{K,U}=\{f\in \Omega:f(K)\subseteq U\}$.
$\Rightarrow\forall s\in J^{-1}(L_{K,U}), K\times \{s\} \subseteq H^{-1}(U)^{open}\subseteq I^2$

By the tube lemma, $\exists V^{open}$ such that $K\times V \subseteq H^{-1}(U)^{open}$ and $s\in V$.

Since $V\subseteq J^{-1}(L_{K,U})$,$\ J$ is continuous.

---

Conversely, suppose there exists a continuous function $J:I\rightarrow \Omega$ such that $J(0)=f$ and $J(1)=g$. Define $H:I^2\rightarrow X$ by $H(t,s)=J(s)(t)$.

**Claim** $H$ is continuous on $I^2$.

For given $U^{open} \subseteq X$, consider $(t,s)\in H^{-1}(U)$.

Put $P=J(s)^{-1}(U)^{open} \subseteq I; Q=J^{-1}(L_{K,U})^{open}\subseteq I$ where $K$ is the closure of $P$, a compact subset of $I$. Then $(t,s)\in P\times Q\subseteq H^{-1}(U)$. Thus $H$ is continuous and the equivalence class should be a path component.

Comment: Can you define more what $\Omega$ is?

Comment: $\Omega$ is a collection of continuous functions from $I$ into $X$ satisfying $f(0)=a $ and $f(1)=b$.

Comment: are you sure that for any open $U$ of $X$, $H^{-1}(U) = P \times Q$ for some $P,Q \subset I$ !!!????

Comment: I assume that $H$ is continuous, because $g$ and $h$ are path homotopic.

Comment: so are you suggesting that all the opens of $I^2$ are of the form $P \times Q$ ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't hold for general?

Comment: well no. $\{U \times V \mid U$ is an open of $X$ and $V$ is an open of $Y \}$ is NOT a topology on $X \times Y$, because it is not preserved by reunion.

Comment: I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: I think the proof does not work. You can't be sure that $s\in Q$.

Comment: Here is a hint: Since $J$ is continuous, so is $1×J:I×I\to I×\Omega$. If you compose $1×J$ with 
$$
\varepsilon:I×\Omega\to X, (x,f)\mapsto f(x)
$$
you get $H$. Can you show that $\varepsilon$ is continuous using the local compactness of $I$ ?

Comment: Thank you,  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: For given $U^{open}\subseteq X$, 

$\forall (x,f)\in \varepsilon^{-1}(U), x\in f^{-1}(U)^{open}\subseteq I$

Hence, $\exists \epsilon >0$ s.t.$(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subseteq f^{-1}(U)$

$$(x,f)\in U_*={(x-\frac{\epsilon}{4},x+\frac{\epsilon}{4})\times L_{K,U}} ^{open} \subseteq \varepsilon^{-1}(U)$$ where $K=[x-\frac{\epsilon}{2},x+\frac{\epsilon}{2}]$.

Comment: Nice, your proof is correct! So what we actually use is the local compactness of $I$ (that every neighborhood contains a compact neighborhood). That means given any triple of spaces $X,Y$, and $Z$, where $Y$ is locally compact, a map $X\to Z^Y$ is equivalent to a map $X\times Y\to Z$.

Comment: One more thing: If you want to reply to someone's comment, add their name with an @ in front of it to your text, like this `@Stefan`. Then the person gets notified. I wouldn't have seen your reply if I had not come back here.

Comment: @Stefan Hamcke Thank you for your clear and helpful explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any spaces $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, a map $f:X\times Y\to Z$ induces a map $\hat f:X\to Z^Y$, where $Z^Y$ denotes the space of maps $Y\to Z$ equipped with the compact-open topology. The proof you gave for the case $X=Y=I$ applies also to the general case, and the main ingredient is the tube lemma.

Now given a map $g:X\to Z^Y$, we may define the function $\bar g:X\times Y\to Z,\, (x,y)\mapsto g(x)(y)$. This function, however, need not be a continuous map. If we want any map $g$ to imply a map $\bar g$, then setting $X=Z^Y$ and $g=1_X$, we see that $\overline{1_X}:(f,y)\mapsto 1_X(f)(y)=f(y)$ must be continuous. On the other hand, if $\varepsilon:(f,y)\mapsto f(y)$, is a map, then given any map $g$, this induces a continuous $\bar g$, as we may write $\bar g$ as the composite $\varepsilon(g\times 1_Y)$.

The proof you gave in the comments already captured the main reason for $\varepsilon$ to be continuous, namely that when $f(y)\in U$, we can find a compact neighborhood $W$ of $y$ such that $f(W)\subseteq U$, and then $L_{W,U}\times W$ is the desired neighborhood of $(f,y)$ such that $\varepsilon$ sends this to $U$.

Comment: Please, do you have an example for *need not be a continuous map*?

Comment: @Sigur: Let $Y=\Bbb Q,Z=\Bbb R$. Then $ε:Z^Y×Y→Z$ is not continuous. If it were, then as $ε(i,0)=0$ has the neighborhood $V=(-1,1)$, there would be a $δ>0$ and a finite number of pairs $(K_i,U_i)$ with $K_i$ compact in $Y$ and $U_i$ open in $Z$ such that each $f:Y→Z$ satisfying $f(K_i)⊂U_i$ sends each $y∈D=[-δ,δ]∩Y$ to $V$. Let $K=⋃_iK_i$. Since $D⊈K$ and $K$ is closed, there are irrationals $a<b$ such that $(a,b)∩Y⊂D∖K$. Now given a map $f$ as above, the map
$$f'(x) = \begin{cases}1,&x∈[a,b]\\f(x),&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
is still in $∩_iW(K_i,U_i)$, but sends any $y∈(a,b)∩Y$ to $1∉V$.

Comment: Good example. I suppose that $i$ is the inclusion $\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{R}$. It makes sense to me. Also, it was important to take closed interval to define $D$! Finally, did you find this example on some reference? If yes, please, could you cite it? I think that there should be a lot of more examples therein. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sigur: No, I actually came up with this example only when you asked for one. I just took the first non-locally-compact space I could think of, and then I looked at the usual proof of the evaluation $ε$ being continuous and where it fails when $Y=\Bbb Q$. Unfortunately, I don't know any source for counterexamples. I'd be interested myself in an example of a map $I\to Z^Y$ such that the corresponding function $I\times Y \to Z$ is not continuous (which you asked for [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365536/number-of-path-components-of-a-function-space)).

Comment: Oh, thanks anyway. As you observed I'm interested in this kind of problems. Regards.

Comment: @Sigur: For more information on function spaces, you could have a look at chapter 5.9 in Brown's *Topology and Groupoids*. [This document](http://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/homotopy/cgwh.pdf) may also be of interest. These two sources also deal with the problem of finding a suitable category of spaces where the evaluation map is continuous and where a map $X\to Z^Y$ is the same as a map $X\times Y \to Z$. This, however, involves changing the product topology slightly.

Comment: Thanks for STRICKLAND's paper. I didn't know that. So let's continue searching for that kind of example you cited above.